# min python version for peewee

Tags: python, dependencies, peewee

Does anyone know the minimum version of python required for [peewee](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/peewee/)? I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `with` with a `__future__` import. It has a minimum of at least 2.5a1.

Comment: peewee is 2.6+ and 3.2+ currently.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that the minimum python requirement is stated in any Peewee documentation, however I can venture an educated guess: per the [github repo readme](https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/blob/master/README.rst),  for flask-peewee (a project by the same author directly related to his peewee project), python 2.5 or higher is required.

It is not certain, but a high likelihood the developer has programmed both projects with the same environment and same minimum version would apply: python 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'll update the readme with the information, but 2.5 is the min.